# How to suppress message box of file missing during silent install of msi?

Tags: windows-installer

I need to suppress a message box that shows a warning message of file missing during silent installation of an msi. This is the dialog that says:

```
Source file not found.
Path\to\file.
Verify that the file exists and you can access it.
```

Comment: why the post has been devoted?

Comment: reply and devote if any mistakes are there... Comments reqd...

Comment: What's the command line you are using? What's the message box look like?  You really haven't given enough information to have a clue what you are seeing.

Comment: Is the file intentionally missing?

Answer (score 1):

If you mark the file to be non-Vital a installation will be able to complete if the file is missing *and* the user chooses to ignore the warning that comes up. In the WiX toolset, you'd need to set the `File` element `Vital` attribute to `'no'`.

Unfortunately, the default button is `Cancel` on the warning dialog which means that silently, the installation will always fail when a file is missing.

You'd have to write a external UI handler (or use something like Burn) to handle that message and send `Ignore`.